# Passing the original caller in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, identity

We currently have a setup like this:

```
lan\john       lan\application1    lan\appService1      lan\appService2 
client ------> website ----------> WCF Service1 ------> WCF Service2
```

So each website/service runs as a different identity account that is setup in active directory. Security checks are based on the identity of the immediate caller (i.e. WCF Service2 would verify that its caller lan\appService1 has the rights to perform that task).

For logging purposes though we need to know who the original caller was (in this example lan\john) so that we can record they did an action. I would like a way to do this in a more secure fashion than is currently being done (passing the string of "lan\john" as a message header with each call). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If its just matter of checking the security of WCF service caller you can checkout the mechanism suggested by msdn [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/13/determining-caller-identity-within-a-wcf-web-service.aspx).

For the entire application if you want to enable the identity impersonation at this stages, you can explore the design pattern [explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx) on msdn.